# How to display a User field on a form only to staff members in Django

Tags: django, forms

I want to enable staff members who view a certain form on my site to change the `Author` field, but if `is_staff` is false it should be assumed that the value must be the current `User`.

So, for instance, I have a `ArticleForm`, such as this:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'text')
```

How can I dynamically adjust whether the `user` field should be shown, based on the status of the `User`?

If I were to use a custom `__init__` function with `user` as parameter, how do I then change whether that field is shown or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'text') 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not user.is_superuser:
            del self.fields['user']
```

Comment: Ah, as easy as that. Thanks :)

Comment: hmm this didn't work for me it says " global name 'user' is not defined " !

Comment: @Hamza That is user error and not an error on behalf of the snippet for anyone else wondering.